# Cordova plugin InAppBrowser is not opening links

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to open a link inside InAppBrowser using Google chrome.
This is my code:
var teste=cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://free.facebook.com/','_blank','location=yes')

I am getting this error message:
chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'https://free.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Answer (score 1):

you can't show **https://free.facebook.com/** inside of chrome using InAppBrowser,
because the header **x-frame-options: DENY** which is sent by facebook.com is denying the browser.

you can see this header and other valuable headers from network tab in the developer tools
[image]

you can read more about the header from here [mdn : X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

this will work like you expected in android.

Comment: If I was running on an Android device would that work?

Comment: actually if you are running this in android, the in-app browser will open a new activity, not an iframe so you won't have any problem